# How do I safely hold on to a C++ const reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-const-reference

#### aka. how do I prevent a `const&` parameter from accidentally binding to a temporary?

We have a class that essentially looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Observer {
  const T* target;

  void observe(const T& x) {
     target = &x;
  }
};
```

That is, these objects will "hold on" to the const-ref they get passed.

We had a bug where the `observe` function accidentally got passed a temporary object - something that can never be valid for this case.

What options do we have to prevent accidentally binding to a temporary?

Changing the signature to `(const T* px)` would work technically (taking the address of a temporary is a compiler warning=error here) it is not very attractive for other reasons.

<sub>Side note: Yeah, this will always have potential lifetime management issues, but so far the real thing worked pretty well because of its limited usage pattern - but passing temporaries accidentally *has* been observed in practice, so we want to possibly address that first.</sub>

Comment: What's wrong with `void observe(T&&) = delete;`?

Comment: `delete` an overload that takes a `T &&` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a rvalue reference overload, and delete it:

```
void observe(const T&& x) = delete;
```

Now a compile error will be issued if someone tries to pass a temporary.

Comment: Could anyone explain how will that work? Does `T&& x` mean that `x` is a reference of a reference? Otherwise, what's the difference between void `observe(const T& x)` and `void observe(const T&& x)`?

Comment: @Angelo It is an rvalue reference.

Comment: What about the non-const `(T&& x) ` overload - is that needed in any way and how does it relate to the overload set?

Comment: @MartinBa It is not needed because a non-const rvalue will still prefer the `const T&&` overload.